# 3G modem side step

Tags: linux, modem, ppp, 3g

I've been tinkering with a Huawei 169 3G modem on Raspbian (Debian) with `wvdial`, gradually improving its penchant for disconnecting. When it does disconnect ppp tries to reconnect but can't because the modem has jumped from USB0/1/2 to USB1/2/3. I'm having trouble working out what process is causing the side step. Clues anybody?

Comment: Anything related in `dmesg`?

Comment: I am guessing that since this question was migrated, your user was not migrated with it. In order to answer comments, you will need to create an account here and link it to your [raspberrypi.se] account.